# Pandas resample signal series with its corresponding label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-resample

I have this table with these columns: **Seconds, Amplitude, Labels, Metadata**.
Basically it's ECG Signal.

You can download the csv here:
https://tmpfiles.org/3951223/question.csv

Here how the data looks like (first page):
[image: first page]

Here is (fourth page):
[image: fourth page]

Here is (fifth page):
[image: fifth page]

Here is (last page):
[image: last page]

As you see that the seconds timestep is **0.004**. How to resample that with desired new timestep such as **0.002** without destructing another columns.

Such as **label_encoding**, that column is intended for machine learning *y label* purpose especially multiclassification problem, it's segmentation region. It's unique value are (24, 1, 27).

While **bound_or_peak** is intended for displaying or plotting purpose of region. It consists 3 bits (max value is 7). If most significant bit set, then it started region to plot (onset). If second bit is set, then it must be peak of ECG signal wave. If least significant bit is set then it must be offset region to plot.

Here is the table produced by this code:

```
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a NumPy matrix with row and column labels
matrix_data = signal.signal_arr

dtype_dict = {'seconds': float, 'amplitude': float, 'label_encoding': int, 'bound_or_peak': int}

# Convert the NumPy matrix to a Pandas DataFrame with labels
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix_data, columns=dtype_dict.keys()).astype(dtype_dict)

# Display the DataFrame
df[:250]
```

What I mean with *without destruction another columns* is: after resampled, another column such as **labels** and **bound_or_peak** are located as is following *df before resampled*. While **amplitude** should have **interpolated** especially linear **interpolated**.

Actually I have idea to ignore **seconds** column. Instead. that column can be compressed in single value such as **frequency sampling**. So converting timestep to frequency sampling is good idea I think. **0.004** means **1/0.004** therefore the frequency sampling is **250**.

Now the problem is how to resample or interpolate the amplitude to another frequency sampling without destructing another columns.

Update:
As commentator said, I should have use textual representation to show table instead of picture:

| index | seconds | amplitude | label_encoding | bound_or_peak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.035 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0.004 | 0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.008 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0.012 | 0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0.016 | 0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.02 | 0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0.024 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0.028 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0.032 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0.036000000000000004 | 0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 0.04 | 0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0.044 | 0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 0.048 | 0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 0.052000000000000005 | 0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 0.056 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 0.06 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 16 | 0.064 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | 0.068 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 18 | 0.07200000000000001 | 0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | 0.076 | 0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | 0.08 | 0.055 | 0 | 0 |
| 21 | 0.084 | 0.04 | 0 | 0 |
| 22 | 0.088 | 0.03 | 0 | 0 |
| 23 | 0.092 | 0.015 | 0 | 0 |
| 24 | 0.096 | 0.0 | 0 | 0 |
| 25 | 0.1 | -0.01 | 0 | 0 |
| 26 | 0.10400000000000001 | -0.02 | 0 | 0 |
| 27 | 0.108 | -0.03 | 0 | 0 |
| 28 | 0.112 | -0.04 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 0.116 | -0.05 | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | 0.12 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 31 | 0.124 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 32 | 0.128 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 33 | 0.132 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 34 | 0.136 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 35 | 0.14 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 36 | 0.14400000000000002 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 37 | 0.148 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 0.152 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 39 | 0.156 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 40 | 0.16 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 41 | 0.164 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 42 | 0.168 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 43 | 0.17200000000000001 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 44 | 0.176 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 45 | 0.18 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 46 | 0.184 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 47 | 0.188 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 48 | 0.192 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 49 | 0.196 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 50 | 0.2 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 51 | 0.20400000000000001 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 52 | 0.20800000000000002 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 53 | 0.212 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 54 | 0.216 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 55 | 0.22 | -0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 56 | 0.224 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 57 | 0.228 | -0.055 | 0 | 0 |
| 58 | 0.232 | -0.055 | 0 | 0 |
| 59 | 0.23600000000000002 | -0.055 | 0 | 0 |
| 60 | 0.24 | -0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 61 | 0.244 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 62 | 0.248 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 63 | 0.252 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 64 | 0.256 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 65 | 0.26 | -0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 66 | 0.264 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 67 | 0.268 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 68 | 0.272 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 69 | 0.276 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 70 | 0.28 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 71 | 0.28400000000000003 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 72 | 0.28800000000000003 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 73 | 0.292 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 74 | 0.296 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 75 | 0.3 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 76 | 0.304 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 77 | 0.308 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 78 | 0.312 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 79 | 0.316 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 80 | 0.32 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 81 | 0.324 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 82 | 0.328 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 83 | 0.332 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 84 | 0.336 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 85 | 0.34 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 86 | 0.34400000000000003 | -0.085 | 24 | 4 |
| 87 | 0.34800000000000003 | -0.08 | 24 | 0 |
| 88 | 0.352 | -0.075 | 24 | 0 |
| 89 | 0.356 | -0.06 | 24 | 0 |
| 90 | 0.36 | -0.045 | 24 | 0 |
| 91 | 0.364 | -0.035 | 24 | 0 |
| 92 | 0.368 | -0.025 | 24 | 0 |
| 93 | 0.372 | -0.025 | 24 | 0 |
| 94 | 0.376 | -0.025 | 24 | 0 |
| 95 | 0.38 | -0.02 | 24 | 0 |
| 96 | 0.384 | -0.015 | 24 | 0 |
| 97 | 0.388 | -0.01 | 24 | 0 |
| 98 | 0.392 | -0.005 | 24 | 0 |
| 99 | 0.396 | 0.005 | 24 | 0 |
| 100 | 0.4 | 0.02 | 24 | 0 |
| 101 | 0.404 | 0.035 | 24 | 0 |
| 102 | 0.40800000000000003 | 0.045 | 24 | 2 |
| 103 | 0.41200000000000003 | 0.05 | 24 | 0 |
| 104 | 0.41600000000000004 | 0.055 | 24 | 0 |
| 105 | 0.42 | 0.05 | 24 | 0 |
| 106 | 0.424 | 0.035 | 24 | 0 |
| 107 | 0.428 | 0.015 | 24 | 0 |
| 108 | 0.432 | -0.005 | 24 | 0 |
| 109 | 0.436 | -0.035 | 24 | 0 |
| 110 | 0.44 | -0.05 | 24 | 0 |
| 111 | 0.444 | -0.065 | 24 | 1 |
| 112 | 0.448 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 113 | 0.452 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 114 | 0.456 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 115 | 0.46 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 116 | 0.464 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 117 | 0.468 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 118 | 0.47200000000000003 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 119 | 0.47600000000000003 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 120 | 0.48 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 121 | 0.484 | -0.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 0.488 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 0.492 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 124 | 0.496 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 125 | 0.5 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 126 | 0.504 | -0.115 | 0 | 0 |
| 127 | 0.508 | -0.115 | 0 | 0 |
| 128 | 0.512 | -0.11 | 0 | 0 |
| 129 | 0.516 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 130 | 0.52 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 131 | 0.524 | -0.105 | 0 | 0 |
| 132 | 0.528 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 133 | 0.532 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 134 | 0.536 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 135 | 0.54 | -0.095 | 0 | 0 |
| 136 | 0.544 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 137 | 0.548 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 138 | 0.552 | -0.08 | 1 | 4 |
| 139 | 0.556 | -0.075 | 1 | 0 |
| 140 | 0.56 | -0.08 | 1 | 0 |
| 141 | 0.5640000000000001 | -0.07 | 1 | 0 |
| 142 | 0.5680000000000001 | -0.025 | 1 | 0 |
| 143 | 0.5720000000000001 | 0.075 | 1 | 0 |
| 144 | 0.5760000000000001 | 0.25 | 1 | 0 |
| 145 | 0.58 | 0.54 | 1 | 0 |
| 146 | 0.584 | 0.96 | 1 | 0 |
| 147 | 0.588 | 1.41 | 1 | 2 |
| 148 | 0.592 | 1.885 | 1 | 0 |
| 149 | 0.596 | 1.735 | 1 | 0 |
| 150 | 0.6 | 1.09 | 1 | 0 |
| 151 | 0.604 | 0.35 | 1 | 0 |
| 152 | 0.608 | -0.455 | 1 | 0 |
| 153 | 0.612 | -0.725 | 1 | 0 |
| 154 | 0.616 | -0.705 | 1 | 0 |
| 155 | 0.62 | -0.54 | 1 | 0 |
| 156 | 0.624 | -0.315 | 1 | 0 |
| 157 | 0.628 | -0.195 | 1 | 0 |
| 158 | 0.632 | -0.115 | 1 | 1 |
| 159 | 0.636 | -0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 160 | 0.64 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 161 | 0.644 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 162 | 0.648 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 163 | 0.652 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 164 | 0.656 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 165 | 0.66 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 166 | 0.664 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 167 | 0.668 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 168 | 0.672 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 169 | 0.676 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 170 | 0.68 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 171 | 0.684 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 172 | 0.6880000000000001 | -0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 173 | 0.6920000000000001 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 174 | 0.6960000000000001 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 175 | 0.7000000000000001 | -0.07 | 0 | 0 |
| 176 | 0.704 | -0.065 | 0 | 0 |
| 177 | 0.708 | -0.06 | 0 | 0 |
| 178 | 0.712 | -0.055 | 0 | 0 |
| 179 | 0.716 | -0.05 | 0 | 0 |
| 180 | 0.72 | -0.045 | 0 | 0 |
| 181 | 0.724 | -0.04 | 0 | 0 |
| 182 | 0.728 | -0.035 | 27 | 4 |
| 183 | 0.732 | -0.035 | 27 | 0 |
| 184 | 0.736 | -0.035 | 27 | 0 |
| 185 | 0.74 | -0.035 | 27 | 0 |
| 186 | 0.744 | -0.035 | 27 | 0 |
| 187 | 0.748 | -0.03 | 27 | 0 |
| 188 | 0.752 | -0.02 | 27 | 0 |
| 189 | 0.756 | -0.01 | 27 | 0 |
| 190 | 0.76 | -0.005 | 27 | 0 |
| 191 | 0.764 | 0.0 | 27 | 0 |
| 192 | 0.768 | 0.005 | 27 | 0 |
| 193 | 0.772 | 0.005 | 27 | 0 |
| 194 | 0.776 | 0.005 | 27 | 0 |
| 195 | 0.78 | 0.01 | 27 | 0 |
| 196 | 0.784 | 0.025 | 27 | 0 |
| 197 | 0.788 | 0.04 | 27 | 0 |
| 198 | 0.792 | 0.045 | 27 | 0 |
| 199 | 0.796 | 0.05 | 27 | 0 |
| 200 | 0.8 | 0.055 | 27 | 0 |
| 201 | 0.804 | 0.055 | 27 | 0 |
| 202 | 0.808 | 0.055 | 27 | 0 |
| 203 | 0.812 | 0.06 | 27 | 0 |
| 204 | 0.8160000000000001 | 0.065 | 27 | 0 |
| 205 | 0.8200000000000001 | 0.07 | 27 | 0 |
| 206 | 0.8240000000000001 | 0.085 | 27 | 0 |
| 207 | 0.8280000000000001 | 0.1 | 27 | 0 |
| 208 | 0.8320000000000001 | 0.105 | 27 | 0 |
| 209 | 0.836 | 0.105 | 27 | 0 |
| 210 | 0.84 | 0.11 | 27 | 0 |
| 211 | 0.844 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 212 | 0.848 | 0.12 | 27 | 0 |
| 213 | 0.852 | 0.125 | 27 | 0 |
| 214 | 0.856 | 0.12 | 27 | 2 |
| 215 | 0.86 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 216 | 0.864 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 217 | 0.868 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 218 | 0.872 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 219 | 0.876 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 220 | 0.88 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 221 | 0.884 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 222 | 0.888 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 223 | 0.892 | 0.115 | 27 | 0 |
| 224 | 0.896 | 0.11 | 27 | 0 |
| 225 | 0.9 | 0.105 | 27 | 0 |
| 226 | 0.904 | 0.1 | 27 | 0 |
| 227 | 0.908 | 0.09 | 27 | 0 |
| 228 | 0.912 | 0.07 | 27 | 0 |
| 229 | 0.916 | 0.05 | 27 | 0 |
| 230 | 0.92 | 0.035 | 27 | 0 |
| 231 | 0.924 | 0.015 | 27 | 0 |
| 232 | 0.928 | -0.005 | 27 | 0 |
| 233 | 0.932 | -0.02 | 27 | 0 |
| 234 | 0.936 | -0.03 | 27 | 0 |
| 235 | 0.9400000000000001 | -0.04 | 27 | 0 |
| 236 | 0.9440000000000001 | -0.05 | 27 | 0 |
| 237 | 0.9480000000000001 | -0.055 | 27 | 0 |
| 238 | 0.9520000000000001 | -0.06 | 27 | 0 |
| 239 | 0.9560000000000001 | -0.07 | 27 | 1 |
| 240 | 0.96 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 241 | 0.964 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 242 | 0.968 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 243 | 0.972 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 244 | 0.976 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 245 | 0.98 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |
| 246 | 0.984 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 247 | 0.988 | -0.075 | 0 | 0 |
| 248 | 0.992 | -0.08 | 0 | 0 |
| 249 | 0.996 | -0.085 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data. Never publish screenshot of it, copy paste and format instead.

Comment: _after resampled, another column such as labels and bound_or_peak are located as is following previous resampled_ is not a coherent description of what should happen to those columns after resample. You need to choose a well-defined aggregation strategy from [Resampler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/resampling.html), perhaps `nearest` - but this choice needs to be deliberate.

Comment: @Reinderien sorry for unclarities, but you got it, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of `resample()`, but you have to make some aggregation decisions.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

content = '''
index   seconds     amplitude   label_encoding  bound_or_peak
0   0.0     0.035   0   0
1   0.004   0.06    0   0
2   0.008   0.065   0   0
3   0.012   0.075   0   0
4   0.016   0.085   0   0
5   0.02    0.075   0   0
6   0.024   0.065   0   0
...
245     0.98    -0.085  0   0
246     0.984   -0.08   0   0
247     0.988   -0.075  0   0
248     0.992   -0.08   0   0
249     0.996   -0.085  0   0
'''
with StringIO(content) as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)
df['seconds'] *= pd.Timedelta(1, 's')
df.set_index('seconds', drop=True, inplace=True)

sampler = df.resample(rule='2ms')
resampled = sampler.nearest()[['index', 'label_encoding']]
resampled['amplitude'] = sampler.interpolate('time')['amplitude']
resampled['bound_or_peak'] = sampler.asfreq(fill_value=0)['bound_or_peak']

pd.options.display.width = 200
pd.options.display.max_columns = 10
print(resampled)
```

```
                        index  label_encoding  amplitude  bound_or_peak
seconds                                                                
0 days 00:00:00             0               0     0.0350              0
0 days 00:00:00.002000      1               0     0.0475              0
0 days 00:00:00.004000      1               0     0.0600              0
0 days 00:00:00.006000      2               0     0.0625              0
0 days 00:00:00.008000      2               0     0.0650              0
...                       ...             ...        ...            ...
0 days 00:00:00.988000    247               0    -0.0750              0
0 days 00:00:00.990000    248               0    -0.0775              0
0 days 00:00:00.992000    248               0    -0.0800              0
0 days 00:00:00.994000    249               0    -0.0825              0
0 days 00:00:00.996000    249               0    -0.0850              0

[499 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: There was error when you include `index` col. But it's fine after I removed it. Okay after I tried, **label_encoding** became what I expect. But the **bound_or_peak** became nearest too. I expect default value for **bound_or_peak** is **0** instead of following the nearest.

Comment: Then change it. You left that unspecified in your question.

Comment: It's okay but I guess I can just use `fillna()`

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira Don't use `fillna` - instead, use the sampler's `asfreq` as I've demonstrated.